# Installing Wazuh Server in Windows Server

Tags: kibana, wazuh

We do have one server [Windows Server 2016] and i want to monitor that server, by installing Wazuh Tool.

I saw the documentation, but still i am getting confused. Should i need to install,

```
Wazuh Server
Wazuh Agent
Kibana
```

in server.? I don't see any article related to installing Wazuh Server in Windows Machine.

After following up the wazuh documentation, i can able to go up to a certain limit.

1. Installed Virtual Box in Windows Server.
2. Downloaded Wazuh OVA file and imported the same into virtual box.
3. Now i can able to connect to Wazuh Server, using the default credentials.

Now i stuck up at one place. I need to get the IP. I tried with 'Ip addr' command. But still, it is showing 127.0.0.1/8

As far as i checked, it is creating some dynamic IP's. Is there a way to setup Static IP. So that, i can able to access Wazuh Web console
through that IP.

Some of my findings:

It seems that the eth0 network interface for the VM does not have an IPv4 address assigned to it.

In the video in the documentation when running 'ip addr' it shows a dynamic IPv4 address as well as the IPv6 address so I suspect that this is the reason you cannot access the web console. This could be caused by the type of network interface you created for the VM in virtual box.

-------- Edited----------

As per your guidence, i did the following things.

Wazuh Server:

1. Virtual Box -> Adapter 1 -> Bridged Adapter
2. Virtual Box -> Adapter 2 -> Host-only Adapter
3. Started the Virtual Box and checked the 'Ip addr' command. Got the following IP's, eth0 [192.168..] and eth1 [10.0..]
4. In browser, i tried https://192.168.. and i can able to login to kibana.

Wazuh Agent:

The server which ever i am going to monitor, i installed Wazuh Agent. In the Wazuh Config file, i need to specify

Here i am bit confused. Should i need to give the actual server IP [where the wazuh server is] or i need to specify the IP's which i am getting in 'Ip Addr' command.?

I have tried all the IP's. When i check the Logs, it is showing like,

start_agent.c:100 at connect_server(): ERROR: (1216): Unable to connect to 'xx.xx.xx.xxx': 'Bad file descriptor'.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reading [the Architecture guide](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/getting-started/architecture.html) for a better understanding of how Wazuh works. Its architecture is based on agents, which means you need to install Wazuh agent on those endpoints you want to monitor (for example, your Windows server), and then connect these agents to a Wazuh Manager server (which need to be installed in a Linux machine, so you will need another server).

Kibana/Splunk are optional and useful tools to index the data generated by the manager for better visualization. I recommend using Kibana and the Elasticsearch Stack.

For the Linux Wazuh Manager server I recommend trying the [all in one deployment](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/installation-guide/open-distro/all-in-one-deployment/index.html), or, if you will have few agents connected and doesn't want to deploy any instance from scratch, you could try the [pre-built Virtual Machine appliance (OVA)](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/virtual-machine/virtual-machine.html?highlight=ova)

I hope this helps you. The best point to start using Wazuh is the [Getting started](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/getting-started/index.html) guide. I recommend you read that first of all.

------------------------ edit --------------------

Hello,

I'm sorry if I weren't clear enough. Wazuh has two main components: Manager (server in the documentation) and Agent.

The manager is also called a server because it serves the Wazuh service itself. That means the part of Wazuh that analyzes security events and generates alerts.

But Wazuh agent (despite its name) is also installed on servers that you want to monitorize and it is used to send security events to the Wazuh Manager (server) so they could be analyzed.

That said, if you want to correctly monitorize a Windows server you need to install the Wazuh Windows agent on it because it is designed to monitorize Windows servers. And you need to connect this agent to a Wazuh server. Here, you have different options:

- You could install the Wazuh Manager in another (Linux) server.
- You could install docker and docker-compose on your Windows server and use the wazuh-docker GitHub repository to deploy a Wazuh manager stack (with Wazuh, Elasticsearch and Kibana) to connect you, agent, to.
- You could install the Wazuh OVA (VM appliance) on Virtualbox or similar software (this Virtual machine has installed by default Wazuh Manager, Elasticsearch and Kibana as well).

I see that you're trying with the 4th, deploying the Wazuh OVA on Virtualbox. Nevertheless, remember that you must have to install the Windows agent as well and connect it to the Wazuh Manager.

Regarding the IP question. My advice here is to enter the VirtualBox configuration for the machine and set up two network interfaces (or adapters). One host-only adapter (which will have a static IP that you could use to connect from your local browser) and other with a bridged adapter (to connect to the internet). Then, I recommend using nmtui (a console user interface for network manager) to set up your static IP as in the attached capture. That should be enough.

[image]

Comment: Hello @RobinHood, I've edited my answer as well. I hope this helps you"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your follow up. Got stucked at one point. can you please help me out.? Edited my question again.